# filter by included entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The error I am facing is

> Delegate 'System.Func< MyWebSiteApp.Models.FontCategory,int,bool >'
>   does not take 1 arguments

```
var s = db.FontCategories.Include("Fonts").
                Where(s=>s.Fonts.Where(s=>s.Inactive == false).ToList();
```

Any clu how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're after the Linq *Any*.  This will return the font categories that contain at least one active font:

```
var s = db.FontCategories.Include("Fonts").
    .Where(s => s.Fonts.Any(s => s.Inactive == false)).ToList();
```

The problem with your existing code is that *Where* expects a `Predicate<FontCategory>` type (ie, a lambda that returns true/false), but your lambda returns `IEnumerable<Font>` instead.  Hence the error.

From the [documentation for Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition.

Comment: Yep. It works! var qqq = db.FontCategories.Include("Fonts").Where(a => a.Fonts.Any(s => s.Inactive == false)).ToList();

Comment: And how to exclude these Inactive fonts from showing them in Fonts collection?

Answer (score 0):

you miss on parentesis an a where clause take a func that take a T and return a bool. the expression shoud be s=>s.somethingBool

```
var fontCandidates = db.FontCategories.Include("Fonts").SelectMany(s => s.Fonts);
var activeFonts = fontCandidates.Where(f => !f.Inactive).ToList();
```